# Return value from getCurrentPosition in Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, asynchronous, return-value

I'm trying to return the position value from the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` function.

In [this](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/index.html#navigatorgeolocationgetcurrentposition) Cordova doc `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` uses the `onSuccess` and `onError` functions to get the position but I need something like this:

```
var onSuccess = function(position) {
  alert('Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude + '\n' + 'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude + '\n' + 'Altitude: ' + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' + 'Accuracy: ' + position.coords.accuracy + '\n' + 'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' + 'Heading: ' + position.coords.heading + '\n' + 'Speed: ' + position.coords.speed + '\n' + 'Timestamp: ' + position.timestamp + '\n');
};
// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
function onError(error) {
  alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```

And what I want is:

```
var p = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
```

How should I return the value from `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` to p?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want and what you can have are two different things. Almost everything in Cordova/Phonegap is asynchronous, which means you cannot do `var p = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);`. You *have* to use the `onSuccess` function to return the value.

If there is no error and you are in `onSuccess`, this is where your code continues, and will use the position returned. Which means you probably have to refactor your code and/or rethink your workflow.